# ERP Integration using C#/Windows Application

Tags: c#, integration, erp

I need to insert some fields of data (example: Customer Phone etc) from outside(Externally) into the already developed/working (Installed) ERP Invoicing application. When I open the ERP application those fields should automatically appear in the application for the particular order in the form. Currently the the external data is entering manually into the ERP application. I need to integrate from the different place to ERP Application using some another application, like C# Windows Application.  We  can access  ERP database. How can I approach this for the solution to the problem using C#/windows application externally.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what approach you used for Integration, but as it seems from your question that you have enough knowledge about their database structure and flow of data you can directly write to the tables to reflect the updated information in that ERP.

But this is not a recommended approach to integrate with any ERP, by directly interacting to their database tables, even if you have access to them and you very well understand the data flow. Integration to any ERP should only be done through API's provided by that ERP, or through some connectors available in market which are recommended by the ERP vendor.

Comment: so if the API can edit the database tables, yo can do too because is like you write your own API integration

Answer (score 0):

You should look for an API or interface your ERP application provides to integrate external applications and/or modules, otherwise, if you have enough knowledge of how this ERP works and underlying database structure, than you can directly interact with the data...

Comment: I know the database structure and tables information, can I use c# desktop application or a webservice to insert data into the ERP (invoicing application) database?

Comment: @Girish It completely depends on what ERP provide to extend its capabilities, if ERP is plugin base application you should read its provided API to gain ability to do what you want.

Comment: @Girish There are some question in my mind, Do you want to deal with database (insert-update) or you just want to insert some information based on something inside the particular form ? what is ERP platform ? is it web base or desktop application ?

Comment: @S.Amani it is a desktop application, it is a simple vb like invoicing application, i need to enter values from remote system to this form. When i say save there in the remote application, those values should insert into the opened application form here. Is it possible ?